# Get Hex value of a Registry Key via VBScirpt

Tags: vbscript, registry

Think this is my target key in registry:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\Majid\0]
"GUID"=hex:60,de,2a,56,51,b2,e0,11,80,01,44,45,53,54,00,00
```

as you can see GUID has a hex value, I want to tell a vb-script to go to this key and stores its hex data into a variable.

For example if target variable is "Target" then its value should be "60,de,2a,56,51,b2,e0,11,80,01,44,45,53,54,00,00"

Any Help is Really Appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the reason you don't yet have an answer is that the premise of your question is misleading if not flawed. The question seems to imply you're asking about a hex number but you're actually asking about binary data. When you export a binary value from the registry the resulting .reg file encodes the value in hex as per your example. You may or may not have realized this, but it's likely been a stumbling block to solving your issue.

So now to answer "How can I convert a binary value to a hex string representation?"

The following code did the job for me. I only use vbscript on occasion so forgive the sloppiness.

```
Dim objRegistry, target, output
Set objRegistry = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
target = objRegistry.RegRead("HKCU\System\Majid\0\GUID")
output = ""
for k = LBound(target,1) To UBound(target,1)
    output = output & hex(target(k)) & ","
next
WScript.echo output
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi jqcAngel, YES IT WORKS, thanks for your help. Well done man. But I have a very small problem, think the hex data is "60,de,2a,56,51,b2,e0,11,80,01,44,45,53,54,00,00" , this script will put a "," at end, then after last 00 we have a ",". How to fix it? And Also is there any way to show letters in lower case not upper case?

Comment: Hi jqcAngel, another small problem, as you can see in my example, the two latest hex values are two zero "00", but your script just show one zero, something like this: 53,54,0,0, . Can you also fix it please?

Comment: Why are you using vbscript if you aren't comfortable tweaking my example to accomplish your goal?
Put the following at the top of the file:

`Function PadDigits(n, totalDigits)  
    PadDigits = Right(String(totalDigits,"0") & n, totalDigits) 
End Function `

Then change the output assignment line to:
output = output & paddigits(0, hex(target(k)))`

Comment: PS Right before you do your echo just remove the last character from the string. Here's a link with info on all of vbscript's text formatting functions
http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_ref_functions.asp

Comment: Hi jqcAngel, I have edited the code with your guide, but I will get this error: "Type mismatch: 'totalDigits)'" , so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Wrote these today.  I still need to figure out where the ",\" is placed in the code, but this one will take a REG_MULTI_SZ value and convert it to the proper hex result as seen in a .reg file.

```
'##### READ A REG_MULTI_SZ VALUE CONVERT TO HEX #####

strComputer = "."

Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")


regHive = "HKLM"
regKey = "Software\template\templateL2"
regValueName = "SAMPLE-Multi_String"
regPath = regHive & "\" & regKey & "\" & regValueName

regValue = oShell.RegRead(regPath)

res = "" 
prefix = "hex(7):"
For Each item In regValue
data = data & item & vbcrlf
        For i=1 To Len(item)
            r = HexIt(Mid(item,i,1))
            res = res & r
        Next
        res = res & "00,00," 'NEW LINE / ENTRY
    Next
        res = res & "00,00" 'FINAL COMPLETION 



'CONVERT EACH CHARACTER TO ASCII THEN TO HEX, ADD ",00," BETWEEN EACH VALUE
Function HexIt(data)
    a = Asc(data)
    h = Hex(a)
    HexIt = h & ",00,"
End Function


WScript.Echo "ACTUAL DATA IN GUI : " & vbCrLf & data & vbCrLf 
WScript.Echo "HEX REPRESENTATION : " & vbCrLf & res & vbCrLf 

WScript.Echo "REG FILE VALUE     : " & vbCrLf & prefix & res & vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one for DWORD

```
'##### READ A DWORD VALUE CONVERT TO HEX #####

strComputer = "."

Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

regHive = "HKLM"
regKey = "Software\template\templateL2"
regValueName = "SAMPLE-Dword"
regPath = regHive & "\" & regKey & "\" & regValueName

regValue = oShell.RegRead(regPath) 'SPECIFY YOUR HIVE\KEY\VALUE HERE
res = "" 
If Len(regvalue) Mod 2 = 0 Then 
    res = "0x"
    leading0 = ""
Else
    res = "0x0"
    leading0 = "0"
End If

WScript.Echo "INPUT DATA IN GUI : " & Hex(regValue)
WScript.Echo "HEX REPRESENTATION: " & res & Hex(regvalue)
WScript.Echo "REG FILE VALUE    : " & "dword:" & leading0 & Hex(regvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

One for REG_EXPAND_SZ

```
'############# READ REG_EXPAND_SZ ##########
strComputer = "."

Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")


regHive = "HKLM"
regKey = "Software\template\templateL2"
regValueName = "Expandable_String"
regPath = regHive & "\" & regKey & "\" & regValueName

regValue = oShell.RegRead(regPath) 
res = "" 
prefix = "hex(2):"

        For i=1 To Len(regValue)
            r = HexIt(Mid(regValue,i,1))
            res = res & r
        Next
        res = res & "00,00" 'NEW LINE / ENTRY



WScript.Echo "INPUT DATA IN GUI : " & regValue
WScript.Echo "HEX REPRESENTATION: " & res 
WScript.Echo "REG FILE VALUE    : " & prefix & res


'CONVERT EACH CHARACTER TO ASCII THEN TO HEX, ADD ",00," BETWEEN EACH VALUE
Function HexIt(data)
    a = Asc(data)
    h = Hex(a)
    HexIt = h & ",00,"
End Function
```